# rails :: how js responses are evaluated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

We know if you use form with remote true and render js as response it works. But I would like to know where those responses are evaluated. I guess I didnt find anything in jquery_ujs.js.

Comment: It still hits the controller. It just returns js instead of html/json.

Comment: its okay, but my question is how that js are evaluated/executed. it should be handled by the ajax callbacks, but it just executes:

`success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                        element.trigger('ajax:success', [data, status, xhr]);}`
I cant find any event `ajax:success` for the form

Answer (score -1):

If your controller has a js response for the create action:

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then, once you submit your form (using the remote: true option), then whatever you put in the create.js.erb file is essentially your ajax:success response.

Comment: okay, but you see ajax:success response is not evaluated rather it calls ` element.trigger('ajax:success', [data, status, xhr]);`. where it is evaluated exactly? I don't see any callback for my form –